# Why some int from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF is not a defined unicode character

Tags: java, unicode

I read from the Java doc of [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), that

> The set of characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF is sometimes referred to
>   as the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)

But I tried the following code, and found there is 2492 int is not defined! Is there any thing wrong? Or I have some misunderstanding? Thanks!

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i = 0x0000; i<0xFFFF;i++)
    {
        if(!Character.isDefined(i))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Output :

> 2492

Comment: Well, the plane has the name "Basic Multilingual Plane", but that's it. The rest of the character slots are reserved for future uses.

Comment: @Binkan, Thansk! So I need to check if the unicode exists before just blindly covert any int in that range into a character?

Comment: Yes, sure... Out of curiosity: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Binkan, I have a requirement that only the unicode characters in some range is legal, now I am writing the unit test to verify if every character in that range is accepted. And then I found this issue :)

Comment: There are quite some character sequences, e.g. a-z, A-Z, 0-9. But better read them up and be careful if you can rely on these.

Comment: Note that even if every available slot in the BMP were assigned, there would still be integers in the range 0xD800 to 0xDFFF that cannot be valid characters, because they are UTF-16 surrogates. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for `isDefined()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDefined(int)) states that a character "is defined" if it has an entry or is in a range in the [UnicodeData file](http://www.unicode.org/Public/7.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt). This identifies the set of code points that have been *assigned* to characters (and it might've been better named `isAssigned()`). As you discovered, not all of the code points in the Basic Multilingual Plane have been assigned to characters yet ([this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Roadmap_to_Unicode_BMP.svg) shows where some of the empty spaces are).

However, even if a code point has not been assigned (that is, `isDefined()` is `false`), it may be assigned in a future version of Unicode, and is still a valid code point. Encoding/decoding and working with unassigned code points is perfectly valid (although, it is a little strange).

Comment: Strongly agree that `isAssigned()` would have made much more sense, since it then corresponds to the name of the Unicode character property represented. Right now, it doesn’t. There is also the issue that [valid Unicode scalar values](http://unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value) exclude the surrogates and continue through the 16 planes above the BMP.  I strongly prefer the ICU [UCharacter](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/lang/UCharacter.html) class over Java’s regular Character class, because Character is disastrously deficient for Unicode work in innumerable ways.